# Failed bootcamp partition, now can't remove it

Tags: macos, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, error

Tried to set up Windows 10 on my Macbook Pro 15" (Mid 2014). Running El Capitan 10.11.3. Windows refused to install (GPT partition only problem?). I followed steps elsewhere to remove and reformat the partition to ExFAT then try and format again through the Windows installer, but this was unsuccessful.

I scrapped the idea and tried to go to Disk Utility to remove the partition. However, if I try to erase the 'Windows' partition (now called Bootcamp), it simply asks me to make another. I can't seem to merge it with the existing Macintosh HD partition?

[image]

Now for the stupid, require telling off part: I didn't create a backup prior to this, and I think my recovery partition is ****ed.

Is my only solution to do the internet restore and start from scratch?

**EDIT:** To clarify, Disk Utility says the volume is functional and I can indeed store stuff there. I just don't want it! See: [image]

Comment: There is no indication that either your OS X 10.11 El Capitan partition or your Recovery partition is damaged. Why do you think so? The Disk Utility normally does not show the Recovery Partition.

Comment: @David Anderson Long story short, I initially had Win 10 working and tried to expand the volume using CampTune. It couldn't find a recovery partition, nor could I create one using [this](http://musings.silvertooth.us/downloads-2/). Since I couldn't get it working, I formatted the volume leaving the result here.

Comment: If you format the BOOTCAMP partition as MS-DOS (FAT), then you should be able to use the Boot Camp Assistant application to remove the partition. If this fails, then commands can be entered in a Terminal application window to remove the partition. I will not post these commands unless necessary.

Comment: This solved the issue, thanks! Managed to reattempt with success so Windows is also now installed.

Comment: Ok, then I will post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you format the BOOTCAMP partition as MS-DOS (FAT), then you should be able to use the Boot Camp Assistant application to remove the partition. If this fails, then commands can be entered in a Terminal application window to remove the partition. I will not post these commands unless necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Single User Mode to repair the disk.

- Restart your mac holding **command + S**
- Wait until you see small **#** sign.
- Type `fsck -fy`
- You should see `The volume (name of the volume) appears to be OK`
- If not - keep repeating the same command

Hope that helps ;)

**UPDATE**

To change a volume you can try to:

- `# cd /Volumes/"Name of Volume"` in your case `#cd/dev/rdisk0s4`
- `# /sbin/fsck -fy`

Comment: Thanks @Eimisas. I get to "The volume (name of the volume) appears to be OK" for dev/rdisk0s2, but I believe the volume in question is rdisk0s4. Any idea how I can check that one?