# How to remove BOOTCAMP partition?

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I'm using a 2015 MacBook Pro (15-inch Retina). I've recently installed Windows using Boot Camp Assistant and now I want to remove it.

To remove the BOOTCAMP partition I have tried the following:

1. Going to Boot Camp Assistant > Continue > Restore
   **Result it was stuck half way.**
2. Going to Disk Utility > click BOOTCAMP partition > Erase > Mac OS
   Extended (Journaled)
   **Result Unmounting disk. Couldn’t open disk. Operation failed…**

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try the answer mentioned in this answer. Let me know if you have any problems with it by commenting @NoahL. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234211/failed-bootcamp-partition-now-cant-remove-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "going to bootcamp assistant -> continue" do you mean [you did something similar to the steps in this Apple support answer](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25916?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)? Note that there are different steps depending on if you have a single or multiple internal drives.

If you are using the Disk Repair Utility, have you tried booting into the Disk Utility (hold down `command+r` when you boot the computer or restart)?

Especially if you have a single internal drive you may also want to [create a bootable USB drive](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372), and then boot to it to use Disk Utility to alter the boot drive partitioning (so the drive is not reading and writing to the same physical media). Holding down `option` when you start allows you to select the startup drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could try booting to internet recovery by holding down Option + Command + R after the computer chimes on boot.  Then you are able to open Disk Utility (not located on the system's hard drive) and try to erase it from there.

Alternatively, you could try clicking on the drive it is installed on (not the partition) and then choose the "Partition" tab.  Here you can click on the BOOTCAMP partition and select the "-" in the bottom left corner, then apply those changes.